# Get props from external redirect Vue

Tags: vue.js, supabase

I am trying to add a reset password functionality to my website via Supabase.
The url that I get from Supabase is like this:
myProjectID.supabase.co/auth/v1/verify?token=x&type=recovery&redirect_to=http://localhost:8080/

How can I get the type and token props from the redirect to my Vue site?
The [docs](https://supabase.io/docs/reference/javascript/reset-password-email) for the password reset